# Get stuck in a piece of JavaScript Finite State Machine code

Tags: javascript, this, fsm

```
var c = console,d = document;
window.onload = function(){
    var Light = function() {
        this.currentState = State.off;
        this.lightSwitch = null;
    };

    Light.prototype.run = function() {
        var _self = this;
        var lightSwitch = d.createElement('button');
        var cvs = d.createElement('canvas');
        cvs.width = '200';
        cvs.height = '200';
        cvs.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        cvs.style.borderRadius = '50%';
        cvs.style.display = 'block';
        lightSwitch.innerHTML = 'turn on';
        this.lightSwitch = d.body.appendChild(lightSwitch);
        this.cvs = d.body.appendChild(cvs);
        this.lightSwitch.onclick = function() {
            _self.currentState.btnPress.call(_self);
        };
    };

    var State = {
        off: {
            btnPress: function() {
                this.lightSwitch.innerHTML = 'turn off';
                this.cvs.style.display = 'none';
                this.currentState = State.on;
            }
        },
        on: {
            btnPress: function() {
                this.lightSwitch.innerHTML = 'turn on';
                this.cvs.style.display = 'block';
                this.currentState = State.off;
            }
        }
    };
    var light = new Light();
    light.run(); 
};
```

I'm learning about FSM mode with this piece of code above, now I get stuck in how it changes state. Can anyone please teach me and here are my questions:

1, Does the `this` keyword in constructor `Light` points to the same context as that `this` in `var _self = this;` ?

2, What happens when

```
this.lightSwitch.onclick = function() {
            _self.currentState.btnPress.call(_self);
        };
```

executing, which context is the valve of _self at that time? Why not `self.btnPress.currentState.call(_self)` because it's seems `currentState` is an attribute of `btnPress` (or maybe not `attribute`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the `this` keyword in constructor `Light` points to the same context as that `this` in `var _self = this;` ?

With common usage, yes.  Unlike a number of other languages, `this` in Javascript is quite dynamic.  But when you do OO like this (or with the ES2015 `class` syntax) `this` works fairly well as expected.  The reason for the introduction of `_self` is that inside this function:

```
this.lightSwitch.onclick = function() {
    _self.currentState.btnPress.call(_self);
};
```

`this` would refer to the DOM element, `lightSwitch`, and you want to refer instead to the `Light` instance.  Saving a reference to it in `_self` is a common technique.

> Why not self.btnPress.currentState.call(_self) because it's seems currentState is an attribute of btnPress(or maybe not "attribute")?

When you start, in the constructor, `currentState` is set to `State.off`.  `State.off` has a `btnPress` property linked to a function.  Called as it is `currentState.call(_self)` sets the `this` property to `_self`, which is the `Light` object itself.  In this way, the `btnPress` functions act like methods of your `Light` object.

You suggestion wouldn't make sense because `_self` (the `Light` object) does not have a `btnPress` property.  It has a `currentState` property, which is an object with a `btnPress` property.

Comment: Hello Scott, do you mean by that if I use: 
    this.currentState.btnPress.call(this). The value of     this will be 
    lightSwitch but not     Light?

Comment: To your answer to question No.2, can I say that    currentState could be 
   State.off or    State.on and that's why it has a     btnPress property

Comment: Yes, if used where it is, `this` is presumably bound to the DOM element labeled `lightswitch`.  That's why `_self` is stored, so you can refer to the correct object.